# Normalizing search text to full text search and where conditions

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

What you want is for users to just type in their search criteria just like they would in Google. Some words, maybe some quoted phrases, maybe a few operators, and have it just work.

A .Net solution is available here:
http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/05/normalizing_sql.html

I am looking for a pure T-SQL version with where support also. (Or VbScript/javascript)

Example: "dog" food price:20..45

should look like this (for mssql):
select * from table t join containstable(desc, '"dog" and food*') k on k.key=t.id
where t.price between 20 and 45

Operators: and, or, near, "", not, * , etc.

Comment: Don't forget to check for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could have this functionality short of writing a complete parser that is programmed with the table relationships and column datatypes that exist on your database.

Comment: I agree, a parser will need to be written.